# Checking 2 dates existing on different forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 forms: Form1 and Form2.

Each form has 2 datetime members: `startdate` and `enddate`

How can I check that Form2.startdate and Form2.enddate is between Form1.startdate and Form1.enddate?

Comment: It's not clear what you ask. [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) that didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you define "between". If you really mean "overlap" then you can use the following algorithm:

```
StartDate1, EndDate1
StartDate2, EndDate2
```

Such that `StartDate1` < `EndDate1` and `StartDate2` < `EndDate2`

They overlap if

```
StartDate2 <= EndDate1 And EndDate2 >= StartDate1
```

If you really mean to determine that one range is wholly contained within another range, then you would use:

```
StartDate2 >= StartDate1 And EndDate2 <= EndDate1
```